# ansible ufw configuration : default config different from expected

Tags: variables, ansible, ufw

```
- name: defaultt policy
  ufw:
    policy: "{{ item.policy }}"
    direction: "{{ item.direction }}"
  with_items: "{{ ufw_default_dict }}"
  become: yes
  notify: reload ufw

ufw_default_dict:
  - { direction: incoming, policy: deny }
  - { direction: outgoing, policy: allow }
  - { direction: routed, policy: allow }
```

I want my ufw default config as follow :
deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)

after using ansible doing the previous task (without any error triggered) I have :
deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
why ?

Comment: If someone had the same pb : it's because the rules take first places and so i couldn't change routed default policy before settings the rules to accept routed

Comment: If you were able to solve this with what you posted in your comment, feel free to add it as an answer to your own question. It's easier for others to find an answer if it's posted as such.

Comment: Right below where you can enter comments, there is a large text box with the heading "Your Answer". You should be able to enter an answer there, and then click "Post Your Answer".

Comment: I have to wait 2 days apparently, but be sure i will do it as soon as I can. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the rules takes first places and so I couldn't change routed default policy before settings the rules to accept routed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What rule did you have to set to accept routed traffic?